# How to peek at the next value in a Javascript Iterator

Tags: javascript, iterator, peek

Let's say I have an iterator:

```
function* someIterator () {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
}

let iter = someIterator();
```

... that I look at the next element to be iterated:

```
let next = iter.next(); // {value: 1, done: false}
```

... and I then use the iterator in a loop:

```
for(let i of iterator)
    console.log(i); 
// 2
// 3
```

The loop will not include the element looked at.  I wish to see the next element while not taking it out of the iteration series.

In other words, I wish to implement:

```
let next = peek(iter); // {value: 1, done: false}, or alternatively just 1

for(let i of iterator)
    console.log(i); 
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

... and I wan't to do it without modifying the code for the iterable function.

What I've tried is in my answer. It works (which is why I made it an answer), but I worry that it builds an object that is more complex than it has to be.  And I worry that it will not work for cases where the 'done' object is something different than `{ value = undefined, done = true }`.  So any improved answers are very much welcome.

Comment: Do you consider an option of implementing a custom extended iterator or you need a solution that works with native iterators?

Comment: If a native iterator can be wrapped or fed into the extended iterator, and if you don't have to iterate it to make that happen, then yes, I would consider it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a bit different idea is to use wrapper that makes an iterator kind of eagier.

```js
function peekable(iterator) {
  let state = iterator.next();

  const _i = (function* (initial) {
    while (!state.done) {
      const current = state.value;
      state = iterator.next();
      const arg = yield current;
    }
    return state.value;
  })()

  _i.peek = () => state;
  return _i;
}

function* someIterator () { yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; }
let iter = peekable(someIterator());

let v = iter.peek();
let peeked = iter.peek();
console.log(peeked.value);

for (let i of iter) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Haven't yet had time to review it deeply, but it's on my radar.

Comment: Okay, definitely voting this up.  I'll leave unaccepted to give a little more time for other ideas.  But thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a `peek` function, I built a `peeker` function that calls `next`, removing the element from the iterator, but then adds it back in by creating an iterable function that first yields the captured element, then yields the remaining items in the iterable.

```js
function peeker(iterator) {
    let peeked = iterator.next();
    let rebuiltIterator = function*() {
        if(peeked.done)
            return;
        yield peeked.value;
        yield* iterator;
    }
    return { peeked, rebuiltIterator };
}

function* someIterator () { yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; }
let iter = someIterator();
let peeked = peeker(iter);

console.log(peeked.peeked);
for(let i of peeked.rebuiltIterator())
    console.log(i);
```

Comment: I cannot imagine any better approach. The only alternative is to implement custom iterators (e.g. [like in this article](https://blog.codewithdan.com/using-the-iterator-pattern-in-javascript/)) but this way does not allow using native syntax. Basically, native iterators can return mutable objects and run side effects, thus you cannot get its `next` value without changing the inner state.

Comment: Hey @Shlang, thanks for looking into it and for the article reference.  If I ever successfully use any of the article's concepts i may update my question or answer.

Answer (score 1):

Translating @Shlang's answer to `AsyncIterables` and TypeScript:

```
type PeekableAsyncIterable<T> = AsyncIterable<T> & {
  peek: () => Promise<T | null>;
}

/**
 * Adds a `peek` method to `AsyncIterable<T>`, which
 * peeks at the next element in the iterable without consuming it.
 */
export const peekable = <T>(asyncIterable: AsyncIterable<T>): PeekableAsyncIterable<T> => {
  let nextElPromise = asyncIterable[Symbol.asyncIterator]().next()

  const it = (async function * () {
    let nonEmpty = true
    while (nonEmpty) {
      const result = await nextElPromise
      nonEmpty = !result.done
      if (nonEmpty) {
        nextElPromise = asyncIterable[Symbol.asyncIterator]().next()
        yield result.value
      }
    }
  })() as unknown as PeekableAsyncIterable<T>

  it.peek = async () => {
    const result = await nextElPromise
    return result.done
      ? null // if you have a `Result<T>` or `Either<T, E>` type, use it here instead of null
      : result.value
  }

  return it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to contribute my way of solving this, based off of [Shlang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61261248/16781396), by creating a `Peekable` class.

Here it is in TypeScript:

```typescript
class Peekable<T> implements Iterator<T, void> {
  public peek: IteratorResult<T, void>;
  constructor(private iterator: Iterator<T, void>) {
    this.peek = iterator.next();
  }
  next() {
    const curr = this.peek;
    this.peek = this.iterator.next();
    return curr;
  }
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

It can be used like any other iterator, only with an extra `peek` property that shows the result of the next iteration:

```typescript
function* countDownFrom(n: number) {
  for (n; n > 0; n--) yield n;
}

const countDown = new Peekable(countDownFrom(15));
for (const num of countDown) {
  console.log(num);
  if (num === 7) {
    console.log(" The value after 7 is:", countDown.peek);
  }
}
```

Comment: `[Symbol.iterator]() { return this; }` should suffice. Or really just change `implements Iterator` into `extends Iterator`.

Comment: @Bergi `Iterator` isn't a class, it's an interface, so it can only be implemented and not extended. Maybe you're thinking of the `Generator` class? As for the `return this`, that's a nice tip, I'm editing it into my answer now.

Comment: I was referring to the prototype shared by array iterators, map iterators, generators etc - the [*iterator helpers* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) will introduce a global `Iterator` class for it